# Cannot turn off recommendations for Start Menu in Windows 11

Tags: windows-11, start-menu, windows-11-v22h2

Please help me understand what I don't understand in the below picture:

[image]

Why do I still see recommendations if I turned them off?

Is there a bug or some kind of weird feature where Microsoft knows better what I need or want?

Is there any way to *permanently* turn off Start Menu's recommendations and either have this part of Start Menu totally removed (invisible) or at least always empty?

Comment: You need to do the other part of the instructions to prevent recomended applications.  You need to remove them from the start menu by right-clicking them and select "remove from list"

Comment: In *Settings > Apps > Advanced app settings*, is "Choose where to get apps" set to "Anywhere"?

Comment: @harrymc This seems to be default setting. At least I don't recall changing it, so I must say: "I have it set to _Anywhere_ for ages". But, thanks for trying to help.

Comment: @Ramhound This is obvious, but manually removing each item is pissing off and tiring. That's why I was asking about something to _prevent_ this. The _solution_ of manual removal is known to me. But, thanks for trying to help.

Comment: @trejder: There is the alternate solution of using a replacement to the Microsoft Start Menu. I'm using [Open-Shell-Menu](https://github.com/Open-Shell/Open-Shell-Menu) and am very happy with it, it's *much* more customizable than Microsoft's.

Comment: @trejder - In my reading it’s one time removing 6 recommendations, then they don’t come back m, because the recommendations are turned off.

Comment: What edition of Windows 11 are you running? Home, Pro, or Enterprise? The reason I ask is that in Pro or Enterprise, you can make use of a group policy setting to disable the feature entirely.

Comment: @TylerH Windows 11 Pro, so I definitely will give a try to your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in way to remove the entire Recommended section. However, there are a couple of built-in ways to *empty* the section, so at least you don't show any items. This does, technically speaking, "turn off" recommendations as you asked, even though having an empty section will still look a little annoying.

1. Create a new DWORD registry value of 1 at the following key location: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer`

   [image: Screenshot of Windows Registry with the relevant registry section and registry setting highlighted]
2. In Pro or Enterprise editions of Windows 11, you can enable a group policy that disables this feature (requires a restart after setting). Open gpedit.msc, and then go to "Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> Start Menu and Taskbar", and enable the policy called "Remove Recommended section from Start Menu":

   [image: Screenshot of group policy editor policy that disables recommended section]

With either of these settings set, your Recommended section in the Start Menu will look like this:

[image: screenshot of empty Recommended section]

For custom solutions, there are myriad free or paid options to replace the Start Menu and Taskbar in part or in whole, like ExplorerPatcher, StartAllBack, or Start11.

Answer (score 1):

The setting you see is just for new Apps, not for all Apps.

There is no overall setting for the Windows 11 Start Menu to not show "Recommended Apps" .

You can remove individual items by right clicking on it. You can issue feedback on the recommendation if you wish.

I tend to ignore this except for those times when I need to conveniently get to an App which is otherwise buried deep in the menu or requires typing a few characters to activate.

Windows 11 is not an ultimately configurable desktop interface.

Comment: I don't know why, but it seems that your answer is directly opposite to my reality. My "Recommended Apps" section is always filled with _newly_ installed apps. All those five items that you can see in a screenshot in my question was added as a result of installing a new app and this new app has been installed just a 5-10 minutes prior to asking. I have never ever seen in that section any recommendation for existing app, that was installed "ages" ago. New installs only. Taking your answer vs. my reality and comments given below my question seems that manual removal is the only "solution".